# Combine Safari Tabs with Multitask View

Tags: safari, iphone, tabs, multitasking

A recent version of Google Chrome on Android included a feature where the browser tabs were each shown as a separate pane in the task switcher view, which was really convenient for my usage. So much so that when they removed it later :( I manually re-enabled it.

I would like to be able to do something similar on my iOS device: make safari (or another browser) tabs appear as separate panes in the multitasking view, so I can use just the one multitasking idiom rather than needing to fumble around with both multitasking and safari tabs.

How can I do this?

The particular device in question is an iPhone 6, running whatever the most recent iOS version is. I am not presently willing to jailbreak my iPhone to accomplish this, since it is a company-owned work-only phone, but installing other apps is not out of the question (don't need to be strictly just free apps, but must be inexpensive).

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to modify the system app switcher in this way (or at all, really) on a stock iOS device. Your best bet is to use wrapper apps for as many of these sites as you can.